# Prometheus Docker container exits

Tags: docker, prometheus, docker-image

Have pulled `docker pull prom/prometheus` image and executed `run` command to launch the container but it exits immediately.

```
# docker run --name prometheus-test -idt 0bc82119c95b /bin/bash

# docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                       PORTS   NAMES
bc29abd91850        0bc82119c95b           "/bin/prometheus /bi…"   23 seconds ago       Exited (1) 22 seconds ago            prometheus-test
```

Even with `docker pull prom/prometheus:v2.23.0` image also same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the daemon-flag - starting a `/bin/bash` together with `-d` isn't useful.

```
# docker run --name prometheus-test -it prom/prometheus /bin/bash
```

When you want to start prometheus without a bash, then just run

```
# docker run --name prometheus-test -d prom/prometheus
```

See docker-hub for more information how to use this image.
https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus/

Answer (score 2):

As I know, `bash` even `sh` do not included in the prometheus image.

```
⋊> ~/C/prometheus on main ⨯ docker run -t -i quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.29.1 /bin/sh                                                                      10:54:46
Error parsing commandline arguments: unexpected /bin/sh
prometheus: error: unexpected /bin/sh
```